# How to make Bootstrap dropdown's vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am developing Angular application. My dropdown is so long I am not able scroll and page also getting ended. Here using `Bootstrap 4.5.0`. How can I add vertical scrollbar in it

This is my code

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMap" ngbDropdownToggle>
 {{ selectedCountry}}
</button>
<div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMap">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let country of mapData">
  <button ngbDropdownItem class="dropdown-item" (click)="mapCountry_selected(country)" >
    {{country.post}}
    </button>
  </ng-container>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried this but not working

```
.ngbDropdownMenu
 {
   max-height: 200px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
 
 .ngbDropdownItem
 {
   max-height: 200px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
.ngbDropdown
{
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Please tag all relevant technologies. Looks like you're using AngularJS or something here. Also tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: you can use `overflow-y:auto` or `overflow-y:scroll`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed this issue by using below code

```
.dropdown-menu { max-height: 280px; overflow-y: auto; min-width: 100% !important; background-attachment: local, local, scroll, scroll; }

.dropdown-item { white-space: normal; }
```

Answer (score 3):

For future readers using **Bootstrap 5**, the dropdown markup has changed slightly as it now uses the `data-bs-` attributes. You can make the dropdown scrollable by setting a `max-height` and `overflow`..

```
.dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 280px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/shJzHGE84z)

Comment: This worked for me with ngb 1.1 and bootstrap 4 (and angular 5.2).

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the ["overflow" attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) in your css-file or directly manipulate the attribute in your style.

If the dropdown is too long vertically, choose the behaviour for [overflow-y](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) that you would like to see

If the dropdown is too wide, choose the behaviour for [overflow-x](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp) that you would like to see.

Possible behaviours include e.g. a permanent scrollbar or clipping of content that extends over the edges of the element.

**Edit:** Also, your assignment of classes to your divs is not valid html, so try changing your code to the following (the class name from your css file has to be in the class tag of the div you want to be affected):

```
<div class="ngbDropdown d-inline-block">
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" 
id="dropdownMap" ngbDropdownToggle>
 {{ selectedCountry}}
</button>
<div class="ngbDropdownMenu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMap">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let country of mapData">
  <button ngbDropdownItem class="dropdown-item" (click)="mapCountry_selected(country)" >
    {{country.post}}
    </button>
  </ng-container>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my answer with working code, hope it helps

Comment: After putting your code getting error `NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbDropdown!`